# Match a date column with a date column in another df and return matching value in R

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes of different size that I am trying to combine in R. The first has 113 rows with a column "MthYr" that can have more than one row the same. The second df has a column for "MthYr" but only has one per month and then values of rates for each of these.

I want to match the dates in the first dataframe with the dates in the second dataframe, and then populate a new column in the first dataframe with the corresponding values of a column in the second.

For example, my first data frame head for the dates looks like this:

```
> head(data$MthYr)
[1] "01/13/2019" "1/13/2019" "03/13/2019" "04/19/2019" "06/19/2019" "06/19/2019"
```

The head for the second looks like this:

```
> head(ratedata)
   MthYr St.Unemployment US.Unemployment
1 1/2019             2.8             4.0
2 2/2019             2.7             3.8
3 3/2019             2.7             3.8
4 4/2019             2.6             3.6
5 5/2019             2.6             3.6
6 6/2019             2.5             3.6
```

I need this to match the MthYr columns and then add 2 columns at the end of the first dataframe where it returns the correct rates for St.Unemployment and US.Unemployment. If this worked correctly, the header of the first should return:

```
> head(data$St.Unemployment)
[1] "2.8" "2.8" "2.7" "2.6" "2.5" "2.5"
> head(data$US.Unemployment)
[1] "4.0" "4.0" "3.8" "3.6" "3.6" "3.6"
```

I have tried this:

```
data <- merge(data, ratedata, by = "MthYr", all.x = TRUE)
```

It is only matching some things though and leaving a bunch of the rows blank

Comment: It seems like matching dates formatted as a string "%m/%d/%Y" with months formatted as a string "%m/%Y" would not match. Have you tried converting the two into the same format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  dates in 'MthYr' is not matching as the ratedata, shows without a 0 prefix for month.  We may either remove the 0 in one or add 0 in other

```
data$MthYr <- sub("^0(\\d+/)\\d+/(\\d{4})", "\\1\\2", data$MthYr)
 merge(data, ratedata, by = "MthYr", all.x = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement akrun’s answer, I see one of your problems has to do with
inconsistencies in the dates format. There might be other ones we cannot
spot in this sample. The second issue is that we have days for one data
frame and only months for the other one. When `merge` cannot find a
match but `all.x = TRUE` the it will create a row for each row in the
first data frame and fill vaues with `NA`.

My suggestion is to use `lubridate` do deal with inconsistencies in the
date data and generate a new `MthYr` column that actualy matches the
second data frames’s format:

```r
# sample data
X = structure(list(MthYr = c("01/13/2019", "1/13/2019", "03/13/2019",
  "04/19/2019", "06/19/2019", "06/19/2019")), row.names = c(NA, -6L),
  class = "data.frame")

X
```

```
       MthYr
1 01/13/2019
2  1/13/2019
3 03/13/2019
4 04/19/2019
5 06/19/2019
6 06/19/2019
```

```r
Y = structure(list(MthYr = c("1/2019", "2/2019", "3/2019", "4/2019", 
"5/2019", "6/2019"), St.Unemployment = c(2.8, 2.7, 2.7, 2.6, 
2.6, 2.5), US.Unemployment = c(4, 3.8, 3.8, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")

Y
```

```
   MthYr St.Unemployment US.Unemployment
1 1/2019             2.8             4.0
2 2/2019             2.7             3.8
3 3/2019             2.7             3.8
4 4/2019             2.6             3.6
5 5/2019             2.6             3.6
6 6/2019             2.5             3.6
```

First keep the original `MthYr` in `X` as a new column and make a proper
`MthYr` that matches that one in `Y` (I’m assuming that one in `Y` is
consistent):

```r
library('lubridate')

X[['noisy_date']] = X[['MthYr']]
X[['MthYr']] = with(X, {
  dts = lubridate::mdy(noisy_date)
  paste(
    lubridate::month(dts),
    lubridate::year(dts),
    sep = '/'
  )
})

X
```

```
   MthYr noisy_date
1 1/2019 01/13/2019
2 1/2019  1/13/2019
3 3/2019 03/13/2019
4 4/2019 04/19/2019
5 6/2019 06/19/2019
6 6/2019 06/19/2019
```

Now we can do the `merge`ing:

```r
merge(X, Y, by = 'MthYr', all.x = TRUE)
```

```
   MthYr noisy_date St.Unemployment US.Unemployment
1 1/2019 01/13/2019             2.8             4.0
2 1/2019  1/13/2019             2.8             4.0
3 3/2019 03/13/2019             2.7             3.8
4 4/2019 04/19/2019             2.6             3.6
5 6/2019 06/19/2019             2.5             3.6
6 6/2019 06/19/2019             2.5             3.6
```